# Can I use dual boot in my Android mobile phone?

Tags: operating-system, dual-boot

I want to know is there any boot loader modifying tool for android so that I can use my cell as dual boot. Like Symbian- Android, Android - Windows Mobile, Android - Java, Android - Bada.

Is it possible.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible to [dual boot Android and Windows Mobile](http://pocketnow.com/tweaks-hacks/how-to-dual-boot-windows-mobile-and-android) or [dual boot multiple different Android ROMs](http://lifehacker.com/5826050/how-to-dual-boot-multiple-roms-on-your-android-phone) or [dual boot Android and WebOS](http://an.droid-life.com/2011/09/01/touchdroid-project-gets-webos-and-android-dual-boot-treatment/).