# Dual booting a tablet with Honeycomb and Ice Cream sandwich?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, tablet, 3.0-honeycomb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use dual boot in my Android mobile phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13069/can-i-use-dual-boot-in-my-android-mobile-phone)

I want to try convince the company I'm developing Jquerymobile Apps for ATM, to invest in a Android device for testing. The Honeycomb emulators are just too doggish and unreliable despite the tweaks I've made to them.

What I'd like to do is have the ability to dual boot of a tablet into A3 or A4 so we can test both as we already have a A2 device.

Is this possible? Suggestions?

Thanks