# Dual booting mobile

Tags: operating-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use dual boot in my Android mobile phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13069/can-i-use-dual-boot-in-my-android-mobile-phone)

Is it possible to dual boot my android mobile(HTC Sensation) with window mango? So that I can use either one of them. I'm not feeling secured with android OS right now.

Answer (score 1):

There have probably been many attempts to deploy Windows Mango into Android Phones, but it hasn't been possible, with the same going to your phone [(XDA-Developers: Windows mobile on HTC Sensation)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-1304941.html).
 So, even though Dual Booting with Android OS is possible on any Android phone [(LifeHacker: Dual Boot Multiple ROMs on Android phone)](http://lifehacker.com/5826050/how-to-dual-boot-multiple-roms-on-your-android-phone), using Windows as the other OS has not been made possible.